# Show all sub categories?

Tags: categories

Is it possible to show all child/sub categories of all parent cats? I have the following hierarchy:

Parent Cat/Tax
-- Sub 1
-- Sub 2
Parent Cat/Tax 2
-- Sub 1
-- Sub 2

I would like to be able to show all the child categories on one template without the parent showing as well. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To exclude parent categories from your term list, you can just pass over them after you have retrieved your term list with [`get_terms`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms)

Example:

```
<?php
$args = array(
  'orderby' => 'name',
  );
$terms = get_terms( 'mytaxname', $args );
 if ( !empty( $terms ) && !is_wp_error( $terms ) ){
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {

        if( 0 == $term->parent )
            continue;

        echo '<a href="' . get_category_link( $term ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a><br/>';
    } 
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I actually figured a way out. I don't have many parent categories so I added the following 'exclude' command and removed the 'parent' command. I will be adding more ID's to cover my parent categories.

```
<?php

        $libargs=array(  
            'hide_empty'        => 0,  
            'exclude'           => array(16), //* Enter ID's of parent categories to exclude from list
            'taxonomy'      => 'mytaxname');  

        ?>
```